# How to connect to GCP in go using cloud.google.com/go/storage library with aksk?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I am writing an application that fetches various metadata from GCP buckets and objects for analytical purposes.

I came across the `cloud.google.com/go/storage`  library in the post below

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#client-libraries

I am currently trying to connect to GCP with `cloud.google.com/go/storage` using access-key,secret-key (aksk)

```
endpoint := option.WithEndpoint("https://storage.googleapis.com")
//create client option from aksk
client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx, endpoint)
if err != nil {
   return nil, fmt.Errorf("storage.NewClient: %v", err)
}
```

I am not able to find any ClientOption which accepts aksk.

PS: I don't want to use any other modes of authentication as it will break the existing architecture

Comment: What are you referring to exactly with AccessKey / SecretKey? What types of authentication / authorization are trying to use?

Comment: What is aksk? I don't know that mode on Google Cloud!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere https://cloud.telestream.net/tutorials/how-to-setting-up-google-cloud-storage/#:~:text=To%20generate%20Access%20Key%20and,already%2C%20click%20on%20Interoperable%20Access. check this link